# ScaleTransform in C#Wpf

Tags: wpf, grid, scaletransform, mscorlib, formatexception

i have some xml code who add a ScaleX of 1 to one of my grid.

Looks like :

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="player1Scale" ScaleX="1" />
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

It works nice. But now **I need to apply a ScaleX of 1 to another grid but with C# code.**
So i did something like that:

```
ScaleTransform myScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
myScaleTransform.ScaleY = 0;
myScaleTransform.ScaleX = 1;
TransformGroup myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
myTransformGroup.Children.Add(myScaleTransform);
grid.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;
```

and **i get an error with no details.** Only

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

So i did some researchs and i didnt find whats wrong with my code >< ?

**Without this part of code my grid is fine.** But as soon I put this ScaleTransform the grid disapears and I get this single line of error.

**I always tried to do**

```
grid.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1, 0);
grid.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1.0d, 0.0d);
grid.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(Convert.ToDouble("1"), Convert.ToDouble("0"));
```

and so many others things that didnt work... So now I need to ask here how can I solve this problem..

I hope somebody can find the answer, I can give you more details if needed.

Thx to read me.

Comment: 1 is default value for ScaleX and ScaleY. no need to assign them explicitly. the tranform in xaml does nothing

Comment: `grid.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1, 0);` on itself doesn't produce erros, though it just collapse element due to 0 scaleY. make it new ScaleTransform(1, 1), and search the error in surrounding code